# Activity Feed Notification sent via SendActivityNotification doesn't correctly navigate to desktop tab app

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

I have a Teams Tab app that is installed in a specific teams channels.

I have a backend service that sends an activity feed notification to a user. The idea is that when the sure clicks on the notification, it should navigate to my Teams Tab app.

The code looks like this...(I've omitted code that isn't useful here)

```
 var encodedContext = Uri.EscapeDataString(JsonSerializer.Serialize(new {subEntityId = "senkwe_test", channelId = channel_id}));

var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Teams.Item.SendActivityNotification.SendActivityNotificationPostRequestBody
{
    Topic = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.TeamworkActivityTopic
    {
        Source = Microsoft.Graph.Models.TeamworkActivityTopicSource.Text,
        Value = "Item Ready For Upload",            
        WebUrl = $"https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/a9715d09-97c3-4bc1-9434-ad4bdf83bf06/Test?context={encodedContext}"
    },
    ActivityType = "itemReadyForUpload",
    PreviewText = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.ItemBody
    {
        Content = "Your item is ready for upload again",
    },
    Recipient = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.TeamworkNotificationRecipient
    {
        OdataType = "microsoft.graph.aadUserNotificationRecipient",
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "userId",  "4169405a-a5dd-4d2b-b68e-ba3ea42915ea"}
        }
    }
};

try
{
    await graphClient.Teams["aff16c68-02d8-48c4-812a-8566cc73f3de"].SendActivityNotification.PostAsync(requestBody);
}
```

The notification is correctly sent to Teams but clicking it opens my Teams App without navigating correctly. See below.

[image]

When I open the uri in **WebUrl** via a browser, Teams opens up on the desktop and correctly. See below.

[image]

How can I ensure that the activity feed notification correctly navigates to my app?